# "useless type qualifier" error

Tags: c, struct

I get the following error with the following code. I tried to figure out where the problem is over Google, but I didn't find anything helpful.

```
Compiling /home/tectu/projects/resources/chibios/ext/lcd/touchpad.c
In file included from /home/tectu/projects/resources/chibios/ext/lcd/touchpad.c:1:0:
/home/tectu/projects/resources/chibios/ext/lcd/touchpad.h:17:1: warning: useless type qualifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

Here's the the code from line 12 to line 17 from `touchpad.h`:

```
volatile struct cal {
    float xm; 
    float ym; 
    float xn; 
    float yn; 
};
```

And here's how I use this struct inside `touchpad.c`:

```
static struct cal cal = { 
    1, 1, 0, 0  
};
```

Can anyone show me the light? :D

Comment: Volatile refers to objects. Your type definition does not define an object. Your `struct cal cal ={1,1,0,0};` *does* define an object. You could put the volatile in front of it.

Comment: Side note: `volatile` is a very specific keyword and is widely misused. Make sure you really need it! See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get an error, just a warning.

And that applies to how you declare your `struct cal`: it is not volatile by itself; the volatile only applies to a concrete variable definition.

So in `static struct cal cal`, your variable `cal` is just `static`, but not `volatile`.

In that sense, the `volatile` declaration is, as the warning says, useless.

Answer (score 8):

`volatile` as a qualifier can be applied to a particular instance of structure.
You are applying it to a type which is useless and the compiler correctly points it out.

Answer (score 6):

`volatile` qualifies a variable, not a type.

Doing:

```
static volatile struct cal {
    float xm; 
    float ym; 
    float xn; 
    float yn; 
} cal;
```

would be legal, as would:

```
struct cal {
    float xm; 
    float ym; 
    float xn; 
    float yn; 
};

static volatile struct cal cal;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `volatile` keyword makes sense with an object. Not a type definition.

Answer (score 0):

The volatile key work should be used with real variables not with type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach a `volatile` qualifier to a `struct` declaration.

But, contrary to the other answers, you can in fact use the `volatile` qualifier on types, but *not* on **structs**.  If you use `typedef`, you can create a volatile type for a struct.

In the following example, `Vol_struct` is actually not volatile, as in the poster's question.  But `Vol_type` will create volatile variables without further qualification:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Declare some structs/types                                           */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* wrong: can't apply volatile qualifier to a struct
   gcc emits warning: useless type qualifier in empty declaration */
volatile struct Vol_struct
{
    int x;
};

/* effectively the same as Vol_struct */
struct Plain_struct
{
    int x;
};

/* you CAN apply volatile qualifier to a type using typedef */
typedef volatile struct
{
    int x;
} Vol_type;


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Declare some variables using the above types                         */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
struct Vol_struct g_vol_struct;                     /* NOT volatile */
struct Plain_struct g_plain_struct;                 /* not volatile */
volatile struct Plain_struct g_vol_plain_struct;    /* volatile */
Vol_type g_vol_type;                                /* volatile */
```